# encoding problem

Tags: php, encoding

In my web page a hyphen symbol shows up as \â€“. I don't know how to resolve this problem, can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

Check if `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` is in the head section of your HTML. Also I think you're speaking about a dash, not hyphen because hyphen is plain ASCII, you could also try using `&mdash;` HTML entity instead.

Comment: `â€“` = e2 80 93 (in Windows-1252) = U+2013 (from UTF-8) = `&ndash;`.